# Calling three stored procedures from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have executed 3 stored procedures. But now I want to call them inside a single procedure

**Proc1**

```
@PTID int
select A.AId from Table1 A  where A.Id = @PID
```

**Proc2**

```
@PID int,
@AID int
Insert into Table2 (PID, AID) values (@PID, @AID)
```

**Proc3**

```
@AID int,
@PID int


Insert into Table3 (AID,WID,PID)
select AD,WID,@PID from Table1 where AID = @AID
```

Now the procedure calling all these 3 procedures

**MAIN PROC**

```
@PTID int;
@PID int;

Declare @aid int
set @aid=EXEC Proc1 @PID  //I want to get a list of aid, but I get ERROR here saying Incorrect Syntax

exec Proc2 (@PID, @aid)

exec Proc3(@aid)
```

My Proc1, Proc2 and Proc3 runs fine. But I get ERROR in `Main Proc`.

If I want to call all these 3 stored procedures in `Main Proc`, how can I achieve that?

**Update :**

Error in `Main Proc`:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.

Comment: Can you add the **ERROR message** you got

Comment: Aren't you missing a parameter on proc3?

Comment: If you want to call procs 2 & 3 once for each row you get from Proc 1, you will need to use a cursor.

Comment: @Lamak I only have 2 columns in Table1, So I dont know how to insert 3 columns in the Table 3, if I get 2 columns from Table1.

Comment: Ok, your question is really vague, we don't know what error you are getting and neither what it is that you want to do

Comment: @Lamak: Again Updated

Comment: Remove the parenthesis in your execution.  It should be `exec Proc2 @PID, @aid` not `exec Proc2 (@PID, @aid)`

Comment: @Siyual But I get error in the **set @aid=EXEC Proc1 @PID** part first.

Comment: You can't do that syntax.  You can't set a value like that.  You can do something like passing in an output variable or just running the code from the proc in your main proc.  But that syntax is flat out invalid.

Comment: How Can I do with output parameter ?

Comment: @user1989 I suppose the better question is:  why are you segmenting your logic into three procedures like this?

Comment: Because these are 3 different things, and I reuse them later if I need .

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `proc3` like this.

```
Insert into Table3 (AID,WID,PID)
select AD,WID,@PID from Table1 where AID = @AID
```

Comment: Table1 only has 2 columns. So, I get those 2 columns and want to insert the 3rd column value which I pass

Comment: @user1989 - That is what am doing

Comment: Yes, I got that. Thanks. Can you please tell, how can I use, these in MAIN PROC.